# acquire Token Silent method not working proper in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, azure-ad-msal

I have set token session expiration time 15 minute on the AAD,

**overviews**

- Login into the web application and getting a token with an expiration time of 15 minutes and storing it in local sessions storage.
- After login calling the timmer method which is running every second. in this method getting token expiration time and set logic to call the acquireTokenSilent method and refresh token silently.

**version**
MSAL : 0.2.4,
Angular : 6

**code**

```html
setTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      const token = sessionStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken');
      if (token) {
        const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
        const base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        const jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
          atob(base64)
            .split('')
            .map(function (c) {
              return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            })
            .join('')
        );
        const sessionPayload = JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
        const date = new Date(0);
        const sessionTimeOut = date.setUTCSeconds(sessionPayload.exp - 2 * 60);
        const currentTime = new Date();
        if (currentTime.valueOf() > sessionTimeOut.valueOf()) {
          this.stopInterval();
          this.getToken();
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  getToken() {
    return this.app.acquireTokenSilent(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(
      (accessToken) => {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken);
        return accessToken;
      },
      (error) => {
        return this.app
          .acquireTokenPopup(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes)
          .then(
            (accessToken) => {
              this.accessToken = accessToken;
              this.saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken);
              return accessToken;
            },
            (err) => {
              console.error('error', error);
            }
          );
      }
    );
  }

  stopInterval() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken: string): void {
    sessionStorage.setItem('msal.idtoken', accessToken);
    this.setTimer();
  }
```

**Issue**
after login in the 13-minute token is refresh but the second time refresh token call is not happening.

**requirement**

Need refresh token every 2 minutes before the token expiration time.

Please Help me, friends.

Thanks!

Comment: `sessionPayload.exp - 2 * 60` ? It should be `(sessionPayload.exp - 2) * 60`.

Comment: I have implemented the latest MSAL angular version (v1.4.3) but still facing an issue 
issue: after login success before 5 minutes of epiration calling acquireTokenSilent method to refresh token but it refreshes only first time second time it open popup to interaction.